# How do I correctly structure this xml with variables?

Tags: php, xml

How do I correctly structure this XML document.  This document will be embedded within a PHP script and send orders to a folder on the server.

Also, can you please look at the FOR EACH loop for products?

Thanks for your help!

```
(Variables from order form)
$order_id = '1234';
$product_id = '5678';
$prodduct_sku = '0123';
$product_retail = '123.45';

define("FILENAME", "orders/order" . $order_id . ".xml");

$xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>\n"; 
$xml_output .= "<document type="850X-02"  timestamp= $timestamp  id="123456789>"; 
$xml_output .= "<order id=" . $order_id .>";

for ($x=0; $x<=100; $x++)
{
   $xml_output .= "<line id=" . $x . "quantity=" . $quantity . />";
   $xml_output .= "<product id=" . $product_id . "supplier_sku=" . $product_sku .    "retail_price=" . $product_retail . />";
}

$xml_output .= "</document>';

// CONVERT THE ARRAY TO A STRING
$str = implode($xml_output);

// WRITE IT INTO THE FILE SYSTEM
file_put_contents(FILENAME, $str);
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code. Also, take a look at [php domdocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 0):

You don't close your order tag. Add `</order>` somewhere after the line loop.

Beyond that, you may consider using an IDE that provides robust xml formatting and validation, or you can use a web-based xml validator to verify that the xml you create is valid.

Another tip for testing xml generation code is to get a valid xml sample for the target system, then refine your code until you can generate that example text. Using file diff tools you can quickly identify things like missing tags, elements instead of attributes, or other common errors.